# Handle an Array of JQuery elements to interact with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

What I am basicly trying to do, is to build an array of JQuery elements in order to interact with the checkboxes, the elements are $(.arms) and $(.neck)

Javascript:

```
var elements = new Array ($('.arms'),$('.neck'));

for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {

elements[i].change = function() {

elements[i].not(this).prop('disabled',this.checked);

});

}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="15000" class="arms"/>$50<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="9400" class="arms"/>$60<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="9500" class="neck"/>$70<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="9600" class="neck"/>$80<br/>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VTShe/1)

Here is what is supposed to be doing, but only works with 1 element: [one element fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2H5kB/11/)

I think I am pretty close but something is not working.

Comment: `$(.arms)` should be `$(".arms")`

Comment: I think you should read up on how jQuery works. jQuery *is* essentially an array of DOM elements. Instead of combining an array of selectors, you can just use one like `$('.arms, .neck');`

Comment: oh, my very bad. I changed, but it still isn't working @roXon

Comment: @HerlandCid it was just an offtopic tip, look at my demo to find out how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VTShe/2/)**</kbd>

```
$('.arms, .neck').change(function(){
    var myClass = $(this).attr('class'); 
    $('.'+myClass).not(this).prop('disabled', this.checked); 
});
```

Comment: Hey! that's not a keyboard key!

Comment: what is myClass basicly doing? I know you might be pretty busy I just want to learn @roXon I couldn't find inbox on this haha

Comment: @HerlandCid If this answer helped you, make sure to accept it. The `myClass` is a variable that's holding the class name of the triggered checkbox. So if the triggered checkb. class name is `neck` doing `$('.'+myClass)` is like doing `$('.neck')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".arms, .neck").on("change", function() {

    $(".arms, .neck").not(this).prop('disabled',this.checked);
});
```

Do the classes together, jQuery handles the arrays.

Comment: Yours doesn't work don't know why :c, but I got it solved, thanks! @QuentinUK

Comment: "It works on my machine." I notice that your Fiddle hasn't got the jQuery library selected.